# Automatically splitting recording files

Tags: recording, software, windows, automation, files

I'm looking for a software (Windows) that may record sound via line-in port in my sound card.

The thing is my recordings are very long (long hours or even days) and I wish the software automatically splitting recording files like  every hour or when file reaches 200 MB etc.

Answer (score 1):

[SureLog](http://www.charliedavy.co.uk/surelog/) can record either continuously or in hourly sections and can name the files according to the date and time. It is actually designed for recording radio output. More information can be found on the site.

(For those on a budget, there is also [a gratis version](http://www.charliedavy.co.uk/surelog-free/) avaliable.)

Comment: Well this software is really good. The price is not good - 75 GBP. Hope someone can suggest a cheaper option?